# How to prevent sensitive UISlider triggering “Value Changed” on touching down and moving until after 10 pixels

Tags: ios, swift, events, uislider, touchesbegan

The `UISlider` is extremely sensitive. For instance, when a user just touches down on a `UISlider`, in most cases, the slider moves and `Value Changed` is called.

I have the below class that aims to prevent/delay the slider from moving until 10 pixels, however it only works partially. `Value Changed` is still called on touching down, so initial movement isn't prevented.

**1 - What different techniques can I employ to prevent the `UISlider` from being extra sensitive and moving only after a delay of 10 pixels are reached?**

**2 - How can I prevent the `UISlider` `Value Changed` triggering instantly when touching down and instead trigger only after at least 10 pixels of movement?**

Code:

```
let DelayPoint:CGFloat = 10

class DelaySlider: UISlider {

    var startPoint:CGPoint?

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if self.startPoint == nil {
          self.startPoint = touches.first?.previousLocationInView(self)
        }


        if self.shouldAllowForSendActionForPoint((touches.first?.locationInView(self))!) {
            super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.startPoint = nil
        super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

    func shouldAllowForSendActionForPoint(location:CGPoint) -> Bool {

        if self.startPoint != nil {

            let xDiff = (self.startPoint?.x)! - location.x
            let yDiff = (self.startPoint?.y)! - location.y

            if (xDiff > DelayPoint || xDiff < -DelayPoint || yDiff > DelayPoint || yDiff < -DelayPoint) {

                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```